# IIS refuses to serve HttpException to Application_Error? What's wrong with my configuration?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am having problems getting IIS to pass HttpException handling through Global.ashx.cs Application_Error. Here is an example of a test project replicating the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Weber
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Write("<html><body><h2>Global Page Error</h2>");
            Response.Write("<p>" + exc.Message + "</p></body></html>");
            Server.ClearError();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see a test url of what should be a custom 404 page at this location with the code above:

http://www.the2016vote.us/nonsense-page

I am not receiving my "Global Page Error". How can I fix this?

Here is my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
            <assemblies />
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx ? Might be helpful in your situation.

Comment: Yes I looked at that page. That page is where I began when creating the example above.